# Relational databases and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, relational-database

I'm using CodeIgniter to build a website, and I want to show a list of construction projects from a database table, which we will simply call `project_table`. For each project I also have an address, stored in another table, `address_table`, each address has a `project_id`, which links it to a project.

I have made a function, get_projects, in my projects model, which is used to get the project information and pass it to the project view, like such:

```
public function index() {
    $data['projects'] = $this->project_model->get_projects();
    $data['title'] = 'Ejendomme';
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('projects/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

My question is how I get the addresses read, linked to the correct projects, and shown. I suppose I could make a function which is called from the view, which loads the address based on `project_id`, but as I understand it, this is really bad practice. Is there a way to call a `get_address` function from the controller, and pass it on to the view, without losing track of which address belongs to which project?

**Update:**
Per request here is the function `get_project()`, which gets the project information from the database. I have considered calling a `get_address()` function inside this, but I am not sure how I would return the addresses from the function.

```
// Function to read all projects from database
public function get_projects() {
    $query = $this->db->get('project_table');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was more useful if you've posted the get_projects method from models.  Anyway, the trick is to make use of Model-View-Controller(MVC) architecture, therefore you put into the model the selection from database. 
Here is an example with a method to extract your data from those two tables:

```
public function get_projects()
{
//for standard mySQL
//select only the db fields that you need
$query = "SELECT pt.*, at.* FROM project_table as pt, address_table as at WHERE pt.project_id = at.project_id";
$db_result = $this->db->query($query);
$result_object = $db_result->result();
/*
here you can add a check for the result (for instance to check if the return is not empty)
*/
return $result_object;
}
```

Now parse the result to a view and play from there with the data.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have added the code for my get_projects() function. What does the pt.* and at`.* mean? is that the table names? (I.e. project_table and address_table in my example)

Comment: pt.* refers to all the columns in the table referenced as "pt" (in the example query above that's project_table)

Comment: I think I somewhat get it now (sorry for being slow, haven't seen that syntax before). So how will I address the different parts of the result object, which is returned?

Comment: see my separate answer, hopefully that helps

Comment: "**pt**" and "**at**" are aliases for those two tables from the query, for instance: instead of writing project_table.* (means select all columns from project_table table) you can write pt.* if you add an alias (keyword "**AS**") to the table (e.g. project_table **as** pt)

Comment: As with the other suggested solution, I have some issues using the data later in the process. It returns an error "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in (...)", which is related to the line: `<?php echo $projects_item['project_name'] ?>`

Comment: Ended up using this solution, though I suppose thy both work equally fine. In either case however, note that the output type has been changed to an object, as opposed to an array. If it is to remain as an array use `$result_object =$db_result->result_array();`

Answer (score 2):

Joining the ideas in the previous answers, you could use the query builder (using CI 3 name) to join the two tables and return all the information you need from that method in the model:

```
public function get_projects() {
    $this->db->from('project_table');
    $this->db->join('adress_table', 'adress_table.project_id', 'project_table.id');

    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

You can learn more about the QueryBuilder Class at the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want to keep all your database queries in the model. You can call other functions in your model by using $this->function_name().

I believe this will achieve what you are after (these go in your model):

```
// Function to read all projects from database
public function get_projects() {
    $results = $this->db->get('ed_projects')->result();
    foreach($results as $r) {
        $r->address = $this->get_address($r->id);
    }
    return $results;
}

// Function to read addresses for a $project_id
private function get_address($project_id) {
    return $this->db->from('project_address_table')
                ->where('project_id', $project_id)
                ->get()->result();
}
```

I would also recommend using the codeigniter active record class (http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) for doing easy database queries like this as it makes it a lot easier to see what your query is doing

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will let you know if I get it to work :-)

Comment: I can get it to read from the database, using the above code, but when I try to use the code i get an error saying "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in (...)". I should probably mention that the project_address_table contains multiple fields. Is it possible to organize these fields, along with the fields in get_project(), before returning it all as an array?

Comment: You can choose what fields to return by adding `->select('field1, field2, field3')` after `$this->db`. You can make the get_address function return as an array by changing `->result()` to
`->result_array()` the same as in your first function.

Sorry the error is occurring as in my example above I changed my first function to return as an object - change `$r->address` to `$r['address']` and that should work